# Get Timezone Offset of Server in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the timezone offset of the physical server running my code? Not some date object or other object in memory.

For example, the following code will output `-4:00:00`:

```
<%= TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(new DateTime()) %>
```

When it should be `-03:00:00` because of daylight savings

Comment: Is your server set to the right timezone?

Comment: Check if Daylight saving applies to your server using [`TimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f14e97.aspx)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`new DateTime()` will give you January 1st 0001, rather than the *current* date/time. I suspect you want the *current* UTC offset... and that's why you're not seeing the daylight saving offset in your current code.

I'd use [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx) instead of `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` - it *may* not affect things, but it would definitely be a better approach. [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) should pretty much replace `TimeZone` in all code. Then you can use [`GetUtcOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378.aspx):

```
var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

(Using `DateTime.Now` *should* work as well, but it involves some magic behind the scenes when there are daylight saving transitions around now. `DateTime` [actually has *four* kinds rather than the advertised three](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/), but it's simpler just to avoid the issue entirely by using `UtcNow`.)

Or of course you could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library instead of all this BCL rubbish ;) (If you're doing a lot of date/time work I'd thoroughly recommend that - obviously - but if you're *only* doing this one bit, it would probably be overkill.)

Comment: The shameless plug is apt. Noda Time makes this a non-issue by just making *sense*.

Comment: @Tragedian: Thanks - validation is always nice :)

Comment: TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now) works for my purposes too

Comment: @user1886419: Yes, that doesn't surprise me - but `TimeZone` is effectively deprecated, and IIRC it doesn't cope with historical changes in rules. I'd really strongly urge you to use `TimeZoneInfo` if you possibly can.

Answer (score 42):

Since .NET 3.5, you can use the following from `DateTimeOffset` to get the current offset.

```
var offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset;
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset.aspx)

Comment: If the server & required timezone offset are same then this is ok i guess, if not we still need to work with object returned from TimezoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById

Comment: @Naga The question was asking how to get the server offset. There is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561075/get-datetime-offset-for-timezone) on how to get "now" at an arbitrary timezone.

Answer (score 12):

There seems to be some difference between how `GetUtcOffset` works with `new DateTime()` and `DateTime.Now`. When I run it in the Central Time Zone, I get:

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(new DateTime()) // -06:00:00

TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)   // -05:00:00
```

It's a bit of a kludge, but I suppose you could also do this:

```
DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow // -05:00:00
```

Comment: Yes, there's a difference - because a time zone may very well have a difference between the offset now and the offset at the start of January 0001.

Comment: @JonSkeet I figured that's what it was, but I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: Also `new DateTime()` has an unspecified `Kind`, whereas `DateTime.Now` is `Local`. Although `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(new DateTime()))` returns the same offset anyway. ;)

Comment: Regarding `DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow`, keep in mind that will probably have a fraction of a millisecond more or less to the actual time zone difference because of the different time of execution of both getters.

Answer (score 0):

When you contract a new `DateTime` object it gets `DateTime.MinValue`
When you get its `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset` you actually get the time offset for that date.

If you use the `DateTime.Now` you will get the current date & time and therefore the current offset.