# How to get Date and time from TimeZone Name

Tags: c#, timezone

If we provide the name of timezone region like `"America/Phoenix"`, is there any way to get the current date and time in C#?

I have tried the following code:-

```
TimeZoneInfo ZoneName = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
DateTime dataTimeByZoneId = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now,System.TimeZoneInfo.Local, ZoneName);
```

but it takes/expects the input as `"US Standard Time Zone"`.
I want the input to be as `"America/Phoenix"`. Please do let me know if we have any options/method in C# to achieve this?

Comment: for handling time and date related tasks I would suggest to use Noda Time. See http://nodatime.org/ for more information.

Comment: check out this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974633/get-timezone-offset-of-server-in-c-sharp). it might help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Time zone id's like `America/Phoenix` come from the [IANA time zone database](http://iana.org/time-zones).  .Net's `TimeZoneInfo` class does not use that data.  See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for details.

To use IANA time zone identifiers in .NET, you should look at [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  Here is how you get the current local time for `America/Phoenix` using Noda Time:

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Phoenix"];
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.InZone(tz);

// Then depending on what your needs are, pick one of the following:
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.LocalDateTime;
DateTime dt = zdt.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
DateTimeOffset dto = zdt.ToDateTimeOffset();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will let you know after executing the code