# Get Datetime Offset for Timezone

Tags: c#, azure

I have a code where I need to find current offset from UTC for Central European Timezone.

My code is deployed in azure app service.

```
var offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.Hours + ":" + 
             DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.Minutes;
```

The problem with above code is, it relies on server time, Even though my App Service is in West Europe, the time zone of Azure App Service is always UTC .

One solution is to change Azure App Service TimeZone to Desired TimeZone and it will work, but i am also looking at getting the offset using code.

Remember I cannot use system datetime to get offset as it's always UTC.

Can I get Current Central Europe DatetimeOffset irrespective of system date time?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this

```
TimeZoneInfo cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");

DateTimeOffset offset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, cet);
```

As described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're not sure about a `TimeZoneId` you can use [GetSystemTimeZones()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones(v=vs.110).aspx) to find it.

An alternative, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netframework-4.7), would be to do something like this

```
DateTime nowCet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, 
    "Central European Standard Time");
```

The nice thing about this is you can easily calculate the difference between two time zones like, for example

```
DateTime newYork = new DateTime(2017, 10, 04, 12, 23, 00);
DateTime berlin = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(newYork, 
    "Eastern Standard Time", "Central European Standard Time");

TimeSpan diff = berlin - newYork;
```

Comment: does this take care of DayLightSavings ?

Comment: @MandarJogalekar I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, when clock changes due to daylight savings, will the method return correct time as per settings at the time?

Comment: @MandarJogalekar - Yes. I guess there could be an issue if you tried to do it while the clocks were changing but I think that that's probably pretty unlikely so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TimeZoneInfo cetInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset cetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.Now, cetInfo);
```

Comment: there isn't ConvertTo method for TimeZoneInfo. but i guess ConvertTime is the option.I will try

Comment: @MandarJogalekar Corrected it. Check the post.

Comment: One-liner: `DateTimeOffset nowCet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTimeOffset.Now, "Central Europe Standard Time");`.

Answer (score 1):

With correct daylight saving offsets (example in CET):

```
        DateTime utcDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime cetDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcDT, "UTC", "Central European Standard Time");

        DateTimeOffset utcDTO = new DateTimeOffset(utcDT);
        DateTimeOffset cetDTO = new DateTimeOffset(cetDT, cetDT - utcDT);

        // Result (with daylight saving)
        //
        // 2021. 06. 24. 7:42:09
        // 2021. 06. 24. 9:42:09
        // 2021. 06. 24. 7:42:09 +00:00
        // 2021. 06. 24. 9:42:09 +02:00
```